# Multi-dimensional Fourier transform of a Gaussian-like function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to get the multi-dimensional Fourier transform of the following function.

$\sum_k a_ke^{-\frac{(\bar{w}_k\cdot \bar{x})^2}{\sigma^2}}$,

where $\bar{w}_i, \bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma$ is a constant. To this end, I think I need to evaluate the following integral and just get a weighted sum.

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-(2\pi i \bar{x} \cdot \epsilon + \frac{(\bar{w} \cdot \bar{x})^2}{\sigma^2} )}d\bar{x}$.

where $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the Fourier index.

I am able to do this if $\bar{x}, \bar{w} \in \mathbb{R}$. But I am stuck with the n-dimensional case. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look Gaussian-like, there is no $\|x\|^2$ or $\|Mx\|^2$

Comment: @reuns Oh sorry my bad. I just edited the question.

Comment: The integral does not exist. If $\bar x$ is orthogonal to $\bar\omega$, then the second summand in the integral is zero. There may be Fourier-transform in the sense of distributions, but I am pretty sure that it won't be a function.

Comment: @Dirk Can you please elaborate your comment? Why would we assume that $\bar{x}$ is orthogonal to $\bar{w}$. Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: There is a subspace of dimension $n-1$ where $\bar x$ is orthogonal to $\bar w$. In this subspace the function $\exp(-(\bar w\cdot\bar x)^2/\sigma^2) it constant 1. So the function of which you want to take the Fourier transform is not integrable and the integral does not exist.

Comment: @Dirk I see. Thank you. But does that mean the Fourier transform of $e^{-(\bar{w}.\bar{x})^2}$  does not exist? I am a bit confused.

Comment: It exists is some other way (as a generalized function aka distribution) but that takes some time to explain and need quite some background. The Wikipedia article is quite short (section "Tempered distributions") and probably not a good entry point. May be this document: https://web.abo.fi/fak/mnf/mate/kurser/fourieranalys/chap3.pdf ?

Comment: @Dirk Thank you. I will go through the resources you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure if this will give you what you want. Why do you want this Fourier transform, anyway? For what do you need it?

Comment: Note that it is enough to figure out the Fourier transform of $\exp(-x_1^2)$ and the rest follows by scaling. If I'm not mistaken, the Fourier transform of this should be a weighted measure supported on line with $x_k=0$, $ k=2,...$.

Comment: @Dirk This is to get the Fourier transform of a specific type of a neural network function. This is not the whole formulation, but a part of it. I will try to follow your last comment and figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help.